# Wordpress menu not working when viewed on mobile

Tags: wordpress, menu, zurb-foundation

I inherited a website with some new business. The menu works fine on the desktop when viewed at full screen. When the browser is sized down and the navigation links are placed into the hamburger menu, it doesn't work. I'm not sure why it isn't working.

If you inspect the element, the links are there, but the nav bar doesn't expand at all. It's using foundation for the menu. I've read the documentation and I'm still not sure why it isn't working. Any guidance is appreciated.

Here's a link to the site: [JordanPlumbing.com](https://jordanplumbingnc.com/)

Comment: Hi Matt, welcome to SO. Please take a look here in order to improve your question(s): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code in `lnm-scripts.min.js`

```
jQuery(function(){if(location.hash!=""){window.location=location.hash.replace("#!","");}

jQuery(document).foundation();jQuery("#preloader").css("width",jQuery(window).width());jQuery("#preloader").css("height",jQuery(document).height());jQuery(".ajax-link").on("click",function(){jQuery(".ajax-link").removeClass("ajax-active");jQuery(this).addClass("ajax-active");});jQuery("ul.children").parent().addClass("page_parent"); jQuery(".slick-background-slider .slick-slide").css("min-width",jQuery(window).width());jQuery("#scrolltoform").click(function(){if(jQuery("#contactForm").length>0){jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery("#contactForm").offset().top},2000);return false;}else{return true;}});});jQuery(window).load(function(){if(jQuery("#click-on-load").length>0){jQuery("#click-on-load").click();}

jQuery(".color-picker").on("click",function(){jQuery(".color-picker").toggleClass("translate");});});jQuery(window).on("resize load",function(){ if(jQuery(window).width()<=1500){var ratio=2560/1440;jQuery(".slick-desktop").css("min-height",jQuery(window).height());jQuery(".slick-desktop").css("min-width",jQuery(window).height()*ratio);jQuery(".slick-desktop").css("left",-((jQuery(".slick-desktop").width()-jQuery(".slick-background-slider .slick-slide").width())/2));jQuery(".slick-desktop").css("position","relative");}

else{jQuery(".slick-desktop").css("min-height","auto");jQuery(".slick-desktop").css("min-width","100%");jQuery(".slick-desktop").css("left","0");}

if(jQuery(".slider-wrapper").width()>jQuery(window).width()){var overflow=(jQuery(".slider-wrapper").width()-jQuery(window).width());var fixPositioning=overflow/2;jQuery(".slider-wrapper").css("left",-fixPositioning);}});jQuery(window).scroll(function(){jQuery("[class*='animate-from-'").each(function(){var theTop=jQuery(window).scrollTop()+(jQuery(window).height()-(jQuery(window).height()/4));var thisTop=jQuery(this).offset().top;if(theTop-250>thisTop){jQuery(this).delay(500).addClass("complete");}});});
```

Comment: Hey Vel, I replaced that code, but it's giving me an error when i inspect the code. 

It's saying this: 

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at lnm-scripts.min.js?ver=8:1